# ROS Answers SE migration: roscd in hydro

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have installed Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 . I have also installed rosbash.
I still do not have command roscd is not PATH env variable. Other ROS related environment variables are correctly set.

Do anyother person facing similar problem?

rgds
Nitin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123706/roscd-in-hydro/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2014-01-28**:
Have you execute 'source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because roscd has to change the working directory of the shell, it is implemented as a bash function and not as a script. This means that you will not find it on your path.

You can add `roscd` to your shell environment by installing rosbash and then sourcing the setup.bash for your distribution (`/opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` for Hydro).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2